# How to write the integral form of a Fox H function when n=p?

Tags: hypergeometric-function

I have a questions regarding Fox H functions

For a general Fox H function if $n=p$, when we write the integral form, does the term with the product from $p+1$ to $n$ disappear ?

Answer (score 1):

In fact the Fox H-function if $n=p$ can reduce to Fox–Wright function, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function for the reason.